# How to handle the background activation event coming from a toast button click in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, toast, background-task

I am trying to have a time triggered background task that displays a toast with button.   "Are you ready to do xyx?" [Yes] [No].   Clicking Yes will then go to a web page.   No will close the toast until the next time period.

In Windows 10 universal apps, I've seen examples where a toast is launched from a universal app with buttons and the buttons are processed in a background task.

I've seen toasts that display a message when the toast is launched from a background task that has no buttons.

What I need to know is how do you process the button if a toast with buttons is launched from a background task.

Is that possible?  If so how?

Here is the code used to display the toast in the background task:

```
namespace BGtask
{
    public sealed class BGTimerTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            try
            {
                SendToast();
            }
            finally
            {
                // And finally release the deferral since we're done
                deferral.Complete();
            }
        }

        private void SendToast()
        {
            ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
            {
                Visual = new ToastVisual()
                {
                    TitleText = new ToastText()
                    {
                        Text = "XYZ"
                    },

                    BodyTextLine1 = new ToastText()
                    {
                        Text = "Are you ready to do xyz?"
                    }
                },

                Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
                {
                    Inputs =
                    {
                        new ToastSelectionBox("selection")
                        {
                            Items =
                            {
                                new ToastSelectionBoxItem("1", "Yes"),
                                new ToastSelectionBoxItem("2", "Not Now"),
                                new ToastSelectionBoxItem("3", "Don't Show Again")
                            },
                            DefaultSelectionBoxItemId = "1"
                        }
                    },
                    Buttons =
                    {

                        new ToastButton("OK", new QueryString()
                        {
                            { "action", "ok" },

                        }.ToString())
                        {
                            ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background
                        },


                    } 
                }
            };

            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(content.GetXml()));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show some dummy code you tried??

Comment: Code added, but the issue is how to process the button in this toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, you already set `ToastActivationType.Background`. That's the correct setting. You will need to process the button in another background task registered from the same application:

```
public sealed class NotificationActionBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail;

        if (details != null)
        {
            string arguments = details.Argument; // button argument
            var userInput = details.UserInput;
            var selection = userInput["selection"] // dropdown value

            // process button
        }
    }
}
```

You need to register this task with a `ToastNotificationActionTrigger`:

```
BackgroundAccessStatus status = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder()
{
    Name = "MyToastTask",
    TaskEntryPoint = "BgTask.NotificationActionBackgroundTask"
};

builder.SetTrigger(new ToastNotificationActionTrigger());

BackgroundTaskRegistration registration = builder.Register();
```

Of course, don't forget to declare the task in the application manifest (you need to check *system event*) and reference the library containing the task from your application.

For more details you can read [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/). **Handling background activation from a toast notification using Windows 10 adaptive template** should be of particular interest to you.

Comment: That worked perfectly.   I didn't realize you could create a second entry in the application manifest that pointed to the second background task,   I'll add an upvote as soon as my rep is high enough.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jack I'm glad, it solved your problem. You can already [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/174150) if it worked for you. You'll also get some reputation from that.